# Charts grid lines style

Tags: c#, charts

I am using the standard charts library from Visual Studio 2010.
The chart works fine but I am unable to change the axis grid line style.
These are the properties already set in Form1.Designers.cs

```
chartArea3.Name = "ChartArea1";
        this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea3);
        legend3.Name = "Legend1";
        this.chart1.Legends.Add(legend3);
        this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 68);
        this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
        series5.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series5.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        series5.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        series5.Legend = "Legend1";
        series5.Name = "Temp";
        series6.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series6.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        series6.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        series6.Legend = "Legend1";
        series6.Name = "Umid";
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series5);
        this.chart1.Series.Add(series6);
        this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(647, 182);
        this.chart1.TabIndex = 8;
        this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval=5;
```

*I would like to have the axis grid type dots or dashdots.* I have tried with:

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineDashStyle.??????
```

but then I do not know how to assign the property and/or if the above partial line of code is correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I got it right:

```
 this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
```

This is working and gives access to the line style of the grid axes.

```
 this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartDashStyle.availableStileSelectionHere;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check out the [ChartDashStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartdashstyle.aspx) enumeration.  Your choices should be `Dash`, `DashDot`, `DashDotDot`, `Dot`, `Solid`, and `NotSet`.

`AxisX` is of type `Charting.Axis` so that's where the line type information is expressed.

So try:

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineDashStyle.Dot
```

or

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineDashStyle.DashDot
```

Comment: Thanks John, but I tried bot lines in my code and does not work. I have amended the code in my post showing the entire sets of properties I have from default and also added.

Comment: Did you invalidate/refresh the chart?  Are you able to see other changes in the chart that you're making the same way that you tried to alter the axis type (like in the same place in your code)?

Comment: The last line in the above code where I set the interval=5 is working fine. All the others lines where there already by default.

Comment: Did you change those in the designer, or hand-add the code there?  Things might not take if you hand-edit the designer code because things get out of sync?

Comment: I tried to add the lines you suggested in the designer. The problem with those two lines is that I get a compiler error.

Comment: I haven't done this in a while but I think that those classes shouldn't be hand-edited.  There may be some comments to that effect around the classes.  If you're getting compile errors when you edit properties through the designer, then something's gotten out of sync.