# Custom gridLines and Axes Chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to design a CDF Chart using chartjs to show probabilities in a graph. Basically, I will always have 100 points starting at 0 to some max number which I calculate beforehand and I want to generate the charts as I attached. Smooth and not many gridLines. I tried using chart type "line", yet it is far off.

Could you please help me out to configure the chart correctly.

[image]

Examples of what I am looking for:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please help me get this answered

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution without autoSkip, using gridline colour options to hide unwanted x axis gridlines. (sorry about my British spelling of 'colour'!)

I can't use autoSkip since my time/x axis labels show new Year, Month, Date only once and I couldn't work out how to not skip the particular labels which indicate a new month, for instance. I finally found that you can define gridline colours in an array, so my solution is to create a gridline colour array, setting the chart background colour to the gridlines I want to hide. In my case, I already send a list of labels with empty values for when I don't want a label and gridline, just a datapoint.

```
var labels = data3json['labels'].split(',');

//set gridline colour to background when label is empty:
var xaxis_gridline_colours = [];
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].length > 0) {
        if (i == 0) {
            xaxis_gridline_colours.push("#cccccc"); //x and y axis!
        } else {
            xaxis_gridline_colours.push("#dddddd"); //visible gridline
        }
    } else {
        xaxis_gridline_colours.push("#ffffff"); //invisible gridline
        //or call a chart background colour variable like:
        //xaxis_gridline_colours.push(chart_bkg_colour);
    }
}
```

Later in the code:

```
chart = new Chart(ctx24, {         
    options: {
        scales: { 
            xAxes: [{
                gridLines: {
                    display: true, //default true   
                    color: xaxis_gridline_colours,

                  etc
```

Answer (score 0):

First about the gridLines, you can in your **chart options** change the **stepSize** of your **xAxes** (put it to 10 for instance) so you will have 10 times less vertical grid Lines (since your xAxes stepSize seems to be 1 by default).
If the big points are bothering you, when you create your datasets you can change their **pointRadius** to 0; this way no points displayed just a smoothline.
Finally you can change the color of the line of each dataset by setting the property **borderColor**.

Take a look at this page for more customization : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that most of you add the line styles only via code. I just spend 1h looking for the settings, as I change it once, but then I couldn't change it again.

How to do it. Post on Stackoverflow pointed me in the right direction.
[Charts grid lines style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239218/charts-grid-lines-style)

Line: this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineDashStyle.Dot

Go to Properties->Chart->Chart Areas and click on 3 dots (...) next collection.

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jRLF.jpg)

In Collection, go to Axes and again click on 3 dots (...) next collection.

[Axes Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcs9Z.jpg)

You will have 2 Axis: X and Y. Select each Axis and go to the required section to change properties. Be careful. They are well hidden, but I tried to highlight all the options. Of course, to perform the custom modification, you will have to code it.

[Axis Collection Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STul6.jpg)